# Proper Java class to represent a date in UTC timezone

Tags: java, rest, datetime, spring-boot, utc

I have a Spring Boot (Jackson marshalling) REST api application where I will be treating all date/times (start and end times for schedules) as being in the UTC timezone. What is the "proper" Java class that I should use in my code for holding these date/times? I feel like we should be explicit and use OffsetDateTime with the internal Timezone as UTC just in case we will need to be switching timezones or printing/logging the dates etc.

Thoughts? Would LocalDateTime be ok to use for simplicity since they will all be UTC?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). LocalDateTime doesn't have any zone information (not even UTC).

To work with jackson, you need to include `jsr310` library for automatic serilization / deserialization of Java 8 Date / Time classes.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Also by default `ObjectMapper` parses date / time in **UTC Zone** which will be helpful in your case.
jsr310 module will be automatically registered by Spring boot. If you want to create your own `ObjectMapper` you need to use

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

// will register all modules on classpath
mapper.findAndRegisterModules();

// only jsr310 module will be registered
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm aware of how to set up Jackson to work properly, my main concern was which classes to use in our Domain objects. I've read that there's a concern/problem with using ZonedDateTime in that it doesn't represent an exact point on the timeline and can change if the rules of a timezone changes. These dates will represent start and end times for events/appointments and will be stored/retrieved from a database

Comment: @KevinM You are confusing some issues. A ZonedDateTime *always* represents a specific moment on the timeline, and *never changes that point*. Think of it as holding an `Instant` & a `ZoneId`. The zone is applied when accessing its value parts (`toString` etc). The problem is that politicians frequently redefine the rules of the time zone. Ex: this past week North Korea gov declared their zone to jump a half-hour forward immediately. So if you had previously scheduled an appointment for 3:00 PM in that zone, now that same appt will read as being 3:30 PM. Same moment, different wall-clock time.

Comment: Ok, so wouldn't that still prove my point that I can't use ZonedDateTime for that reason? The documentation seemed to indicate that OffsetDateTime should be used in most cases because that specific time with that specific offset will never change?

Answer (score 3):

If choosing UTC as a time zone neutral representation — which is a good thought — I suggest `Instant` from `java.time`. An `Instant` is a point in time. Conceptually it doesn’t have a time zone. It sounds like this would be an advantage. You can switch time zones all that you want later, and your points in time will stay the same. An `Instant` can be parsed from an ISO 8601 string in UTC using its `parse` method (for example `2018-12-31T23:37:45.975Z`). And its `toString` produces the same, still always in UTC.

If you want an explicit representation of the fact that your date-time is in UTC, you may use an `OffsetDateTime` with offset `ZoneOffset.UTC`. Since you say that your times are *always* in UTC, I would consider it redundant.